# I haven't been in contact with my husband for two years because of abuse; am I divorced and do I need iddat?

Tags: talaq

I am a Allah-fearing person and I need to find out if I am divorced according to Islam.

I am a young girl aged 30. My husband use to hit me, so I called the police on him and he was kicked out of the house. I can do this because I live in the UK.  It's been two years now since this happened.  He doesn't contact me and he has also remarried.

Now even I want to remarry and also start a new life. But I don't know if I am divorced and when to do my iddat and if I can get married again?

Comment: If everything else has failed after your best efforts, have you tried to take a khula and return back the mahr to him? https://islamqa.info/en/26247

Comment: You need to obtain divorce and then to observe iddah. Simply separating does not count.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Iddah required if the couple has been seperate for a time before divorce?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/34996/is-iddah-required-if-the-couple-has-been-seperate-for-a-time-before-divorce)

Answer (score -1):

AoA brothers and sisters,
You need to obtain divorce and observe iddah before remarrying, otherwise it could be considered cheating (altho I'm not too sure)
Hope this helped and answered!
-Amber