# Regarding Iddah after Death of husband and no relation for 9 years between them

Tags: iddah

A lady is living without her husband from last 9 years  as her husband is went abroad to his children and  for nationality. There is always fight between them and didn’t even talk each other fir last years .Her husband has died now.

The lady was trying for khulla now but not yet done and he died.

My Question is it necessary for her to complete 4 months 10 days fir her iddah or 40 days are enough as they are not in relation fir more than 9 years.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q &A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. The answer of this question is mainly the same as [Iddah for a couple that has been separated for a time before divorce](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/34996/is-iddah-required-if-the-couple-has-been-seperate-for-a-time-before-divorce) in the case here the only difference is death is the reason for 'Iddah observation and therefore the corresponding 'Iddah (length) must be observed.